# How to disable dates before today date in DatePickerDialog Android

Tags: android, datepicker, fragment, datepickerdialog

I want to disable the dates before today's date in the **DatePickerDialog**. I am new in android please suggest me how can I do this. Here is my code that I have written for DatePickerDialog. I'm extending the Fragment class.
Please Help me :)

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);


        CheckInDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CheckInDate);

        CheckOutDate = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.CheckOutDate);

        CheckInDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == CheckInDate) {

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                                                      int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

                                    year = selectedYear;
                                    month = selectedMonth +1;
                                    day = selectedDay;


                                    // set selected date into textview
                                    CheckInDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day)
                                            .append("/").append(month).append("/").append(year)
                                            .append(" "));



                                }
                            }, year, month, day);
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });

        CheckOutDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (v == CheckOutDate) {

                    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                                    CheckOutDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                                }
                            }, year, month, day);
                    datePickerDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }}
```

Comment: By simply getting the today's date and use an if statement checking if(selected_date.before(current_date)){//Do Stuff}

Comment: Code ? :( @shree Please help me yaar :)

Comment: you need to check in onDateSet if the date is before toaday then dont do anything other wise do whatever you want

Comment: @Rushi Answers are coming, Kindly discuss with them you will get the solution.

Comment: @Rushi check my answer below it is exactly same to your needs.

Comment: @MustanserIqbal u have example code ?

Comment: @Rushi Check my answer and paste the code in your onDateSet

Comment: @Rushi i have added the answer.. check it please

Comment: private void openDatePicker Where to put this line in my fragment class ?

Answer (score 1):

Use setMinDate function of DatePicker

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Working code is below

```
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // add here +1 if you don't
                                              //want user to select current date also
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, mDay);
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        if(cal.before(c)) {
                            //toast("Select valid date please.");
                            // notify user about wrong date.
                            return;
                        }
                        StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder();
                        //date.delete(0, date.length());
                        date.append((dayOfMonth<10?"0":"")).append(dayOfMonth)
                          .append("-").append((monthOfYear + 1) < 10 ? "0" : "")
                          .append((monthOfYear+1)).append("-").append(year);
                        //text.setText(date.toString());
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        dpd.show();
```

Hope it'll work.

Comment: Thank you bro :D  I'm checking

Comment: Remove the line ...toast is method in my case.

Comment: DatePickerDialog() in DatePickerDialog cannot be applied :(

Comment: You can, if it fits your requirement.

Comment: datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
datePickerDialog.show(); and this code ?

Comment: `setMinDate` and `show` functions are called in method..so no need to add again.

Comment: Thank you bro its working :* :* but not showing current date :( +1 day showing

Comment: `int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1;` change this by `int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`..Don't forget to close the question.:)

Comment: love u bro :* :* :* :*

Comment: I need Teacher like you :)  can i add u in fb or ? etc :P

Comment: ELITE u der ? I need help

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year_x = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month_x = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    switch (id) {
        case DILOG_ID:
            // set date picker as current date
            DatePickerDialog _date = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), datePickerlistner, year_x, month_x,
                    day_x) {
                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    if (year < year_x)
                        view.updateDate(year_x, month_x, day_x);

                    if (monthOfYear < month_x && year == year_x)
                        view.updateDate(year_x, month_x, day_x);

                    if (dayOfMonth < day_x && year == year_x && monthOfYear == month_x)
                        view.updateDate(year_x, month_x, day_x);

                }
            };
            return _date;
    }
    return null;
}

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerlistner = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        year_x = year;
        month_x = monthOfYear;
        day_x = dayOfMonth;
        btn_date.setText(day_x + "/" + (month_x + 1) + "/" + year_x);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you bro :D  I'm checking

Comment: onCreateDialog in Fragment class never used :(

Comment: are you importing android.app.Fragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this...

 DatePickerDialog da = new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener,mYear, mMonth, mDay);
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();      c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
 Date newDate = c.getTime();
 da.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime()-(newDate.getTime()%(24*60*60*1000)));
```

May it help!

Comment: Thank you bro :D  I'm checking

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your Date set

```
 SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //Format of Date
  Date current = dfDate.parse(String.valueOf(year) + "-" +
 String.valueOf(month) + "-" + String.valueOf(day));//Converting the current Date
             Date selected = dfDate.parse(String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-" + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)); //Converting the selected date
```

//Then Simply Check by doing below code

```
    if (selected.before(current)) {
//Do Stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this i also find this on StackOverFlow about 2 months ago but don't remember the link so adding as an answer

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class MyPicker extends DatePickerDialog {
    private int maxYear = 0;
    private int maxMonth = 0;
    private int maxDay = 0;

    private int minYear = 0;
    private int minMonth = 0;
    private int minDay = 0;
    private Calendar m_minDateCalendar, m_maxDateCalendar, m_calendar;

    private boolean m_fired = false;

    public MyPicker(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack,
            Calendar p_minCalendar, Calendar p_maxCalendar,
            Calendar p_currentCalendar) {
        super(context, callBack, p_currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                p_currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), p_currentCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        m_minDateCalendar = (Calendar) p_minCalendar.clone();
        m_maxDateCalendar = (Calendar) p_maxCalendar.clone();
        m_calendar = (Calendar) p_currentCalendar.clone();

        this.minDay = m_minDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        this.minMonth = m_minDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        this.minYear = m_minDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        this.maxDay = m_maxDateCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        this.maxMonth = m_maxDateCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        this.maxYear = m_maxDateCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        try {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                m_fired = false;
                this.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(
                        m_maxDateCalendar.getTime().getTime());
                this.getDatePicker().setMinDate(
                        m_minDateCalendar.getTime().getTime());
            } else {
                m_fired = true;
            }
        } catch (Throwable p_e) {

            Log.d("m_maxDateCalendar", ""
                    + m_maxDateCalendar.getTime().getTime());
            Log.d("m_minDateCalendar", ""
                    + m_minDateCalendar.getTime().getTime());
            Log.d("m_calendar", "" + m_calendar.getTime().getTime());
            p_e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker p_view, int p_year, int p_monthOfYear,
            int p_dayOfMonth) {
        super.onDateChanged(p_view, p_year, p_monthOfYear, p_dayOfMonth);

        if (m_fired) {
            m_calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, p_year);
            m_calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, p_monthOfYear);
            m_calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, p_dayOfMonth);

            if (m_calendar.after(m_maxDateCalendar)) {
                m_fired = true;
                if (maxMonth > 11) {
                    maxMonth = 11;
                }
                p_view.updateDate(maxYear, maxMonth, maxDay);
            } else if (m_calendar.before(m_minDateCalendar)) {
                m_fired = true;
                if (minMonth > 11) {
                    minMonth = 11;
                }
                p_view.updateDate(minYear, minMonth, minDay);
            } else {
                m_fired = true;
                p_view.updateDate(p_year, p_monthOfYear, p_dayOfMonth);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

in your activity use this method

```
private void openDatePicker(int month, int day, int year) {
        try {

            Log.e("calender", "MONTH = " + month);
            Log.e("calender", "DAY_OF_WEEK = " + day);
            Log.e("calender", "YEAR = " + year);

            m_calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, month);
            m_calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, day);
            m_calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

            int p_minYear, p_minMonth, p_minDay;
            int p_maxYear, p_maxMonth, p_maxDay;

            p_minDay = 1;
            p_minMonth = 0;
            p_minYear = 1950;

            p_maxDay = 31;
            p_maxMonth = 11;
            p_maxYear = 2015;

            Calendar m_maxDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            m_maxDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, p_maxYear);
            m_maxDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, p_maxMonth);
            m_maxDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, p_maxDay);

            Calendar m_minDateCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            m_minDateCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, p_minYear);
            m_minDateCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, p_minMonth);
            m_minDateCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, p_minDay);

            new MyPicker(m_context, m_datePickerListener, m_minDateCalendar,
                    m_maxDateCalendar, m_calendar).show();
        } catch (Throwable p_e) {
            // Have suppressed the exception
            p_e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


m_datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker p_view, int p_year,
                    int p_monthOfYear, int p_dayOfMonth) {
                m_calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, p_year);
                m_calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, p_monthOfYear);
                m_calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, p_dayOfMonth);

                date_picker.setText(""
                        + m_dateFormat.format(m_calendar.getTime()));

            }
        };
```

Comment: private void openDatePicker Where to put this line in my fragment class ?

Comment: its a method. you can add any where in your fragment.

Comment: Its very complicated bez me new to android :P but bro thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                Log.d("Day", "Day" + (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - 1));
                c.set(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) - 1);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day - 1);

                    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
                    return dialog;


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting minumum and maximum date for the DatePickerDialog is not enough. User can click on the year field and select any year.

You should also set year range on the DatePicker like this:

```
datePicker.setYearRange(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    date_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("en", "GB");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("en", "GB"));

            private int mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            private int mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            private int mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            //show dialog
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(DetailsActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    dateSelected = year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;
                    checkin_date_btn.setText(dateSelected);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            // Disable before today
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }

    });
```